# Wordpress default logo

Tags: wordpress

I am working a new Wordpress theme.
The theme will have the option to set a logo in the customizer as normal.
This is working.

However, I want the theme to automatically set a DEFAULT logo.
If the user doesn't define a logo in the customizer, then the default logo will display automatically.
I have an image called logo.jpg in a folder call img in the theme root.

I am using this code to set the default logo but it is not working:

```
add_filter('get_custom_logo',function($html){
if(empty($html)) { 
   $html = '<img src = get_template_uri() . "/img/logo.jpg" >'; 
} 
return $html;
});
```

Any ideas? Is it my syntax with a mix of " and '?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.`'<img src ="'. get_template_uri() . '/img/logo.jpg" >'; `

Answer (score 0):

You had a mistake in the string concatenation.

P.S. Please, don't use anonymous functions in filters. Because it's not possible to remove or change this filter in child-theme for example.

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'apply_default_logo' );
function apply_default_logo( $html ){
    if( empty( $html ) ) { 
        $html = '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '"/img/logo.jpg">'; 
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick,Thanks for coming back - much appreciated. The code you provided is not showing any errors but also is not setting a default logo. Any thoughts? Thanks,

Comment: @AlanisTuring, there was an error with funciton name `get_template_uri()` can you try to replace it with `get_template_directory_uri()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but no luck - default logo still not showing.

Comment: Here is the updated code I am using:
   
    add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'apply_default_logo' );
    function apply_default_logo( $html ){
       if( empty( $html ) ) { 
      $html = '<img src="' . get_template_uri() . '"/img/logo.jpg">'; 
     }
     return $html;
     }